# Getting a response in Lambda from DynamoDB with key value pairs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Bear with me as I am learning Lambda. I have a simple collection in DynamoDB with this model

```
{
  id: String,
  question: String,
  answer: String,
  learned: Boolean
}
```

And my Lambda function like this (With the help of an AWS Employee)

```
import { DynamoDBClient, ScanCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

const client = new DynamoDBClient({});

export const handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
  
const command = new ScanCommand({
    TableName: "Vocabulary",
  });

  const response = await client.send(command);

  response.Items.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(`${item}`);
  });
  return response;
};
```

This gives me a successful response but it's a weird one! Looks like this

```
{
  "question": {
    "S": "What is the name of your Judo organization?"
  },
  "learned": {
    "BOOL": false
  },
  "Id": {
    "S": "2"
  },
  "answer": {
    "S": "United States Judo Association"
  }
}
```

Is this a misconfiguration on my table in DynamoDB or do I need to rework my Lambda to give me a different response. I was expecting

```
{
  "question":  "What is the name of your Judo organization?",
  "learned":  false,
  "Id": "2",
  "answer": "United States Judo Association"
}
```

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

Maybe I wasn't too clear. I'm not interested in returning the datatype in my response. I'm only interested in the key value pair. Unless, in my ignorance, this is something that is only visible in a Lambda test but the actual json API will not contain it. Is that the case. Like I said, guys, I'm very new at this. I'm learning

Comment: It's returning the data and the type of each data element.

Comment: Yeah I see that. Do you how it not make it do that? lol

Comment: Is that normal? Please keep in mind, my experience in Lambda development is a week old lol 15 yrs in Front End dev but never done this. So, if this is normal, is there a something I need to do jsonify this response into an Array of objects without datatypes?

Comment: These are [Data type descriptors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html) that DynamoDB uses to describe the data type of each element.  If you want to convert it, use [unmarshall in util-dynamodb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-util-dynamodb/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type descriptors you are seeing are because you use the low level client, which returns DynamoDB JSON. If you would like native JSON then you need to use the Document Client.

*Notice how I take the low level client, and pass it to construct the high level client:*

```
const { DynamoDBClient } = require(“@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb”);
const { DynamoDBDocumentClient, ScanCommand } = require(“@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb”);

const client = new DynamoDBClient({});
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);

export const handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
  
const command = new ScanCommand({
    TableName: "Vocabulary",
  });

  const response = await docClient.send(command);

  response.Items.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(`${item}`);
  });
  return response;
};
```

The Document client works for both reading and writing, meaning you can read and update items using native JSON and not think about the DynamoDB low level JSON.

You can read more about it from my blog here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/exploring-amazon-dynamodb-sdk-clients/

Comment: Thanks again Leeroy! You helped on my other question as well. I really appreciate. You are kinda reminded about the humble beginnings when you come back to learn something completely foreign all over again haha. I'm struggling here!

BTW, The only thing I had to change on this was the requires and change them to imports. As you can see, I am learning ;)

Comment: Yea, with everything new it takes some time to learn, so be patient. Here, you simply needed to change to a higher level client to abstract you from the type descriptors.

Comment: Understood. It's working great. I'm diving into PUT methods now, soI'm sure I'll be asking a lot soon. It's exciting though!

Answer (score 1):

To get the output you'd like would be pretty straight forward if not super flexible.  Something like (untested):

```
import { DynamoDBClient, ScanCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

const client = new DynamoDBClient({});

export const handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
  
    const command = new ScanCommand({
        TableName: "Vocabulary",
    });

    const response = await client.send(command);
    var container = {};

    response.Items.forEach(function (item) {
        var itemData = {
            Id: item.id.S
            question: item.question.S
            answer: item.answer.S
            learned: item.learned.BOOL
        };

        container.push(itemData);
    });

    // container is an array of the items you want
}
```

The downside is that you're hard coding the column names here.  As a NoSQL database each row could have a variable number of columns and you're not accounting for that.  That would take a `describeTable` call but let's see if this is what you're looking for currently.

Comment: I’ll check it out in the morning. It makes sense to me tho. Thanks a lot